# How to fix the unit test issue in my case?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

I am trying to unit test two functions codes and keep getting error of undefined object.

my controller

```
vm = this;
//always fire first in the app
vm.getCompany = function() {
    api.getCompany(function(res){        
        //do stuff
    })
}

//always fire second in the app
vm.getEmployee = function() {
    api.getEmployee(function(res){
        //do stuff
    })
}
```

api service

```
var company;

function getCompany() {
   var company;
   var q = $q.defer();
   var url = ‘something.com’;

   anotherApi.getCompany(url).then(function(comp){
          company = comp;
          q.resolve(company)
    })
}

function getEmployee = function() {
    var name = company.name
    var url = ‘something.com/’ + name;
    var q = $q.defer();
    anotherApi.getEmployee(url).then(function(employee){
          q.resolve(employee)
    })
}
```

unit test.

```
beforeEach(function(){
   module(‘myApp);
        inject(function ($injector) {
            $controller = $injector.get('$controller');
            $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
            $scope = $rootScope.$new();
            $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
            api = $injector.get('api');
        });

         vm = $controller'myCtrl', {
            $scope : $scope
        });

})

describe (‘test’, function(){
    it(‘should get company’, function(){
         vm.getCompany();
         $httpBackend.flush();
         // stuff and works
    })
    it(‘should get Employee’, function(){
        vm.getEmployee()
        $httpBackend.flush();
        //getting error says 
        //'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'company.name’)
    })
})
```

I am getting `'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'company.name’)`
under `getEmployee` function in service.

I have tried many different ways but still not sure how to fix it, can someone help me about it? Thanks!

Comment: How does `vm.employee` relate to `getEmployee`?

Comment: vm.employee will be set after getEmployee is called. but the problem is I can't get the valid company.name in unit test. It works in the app

Comment: because your second test to get the employee is happening independently from the test to get the company, at the time you make the call to get the employee, there is no "company" because you are relying on the getCompany to have been called first.

Comment: @mcgraphix that's my suspicion too. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: can you update your question with the entire service code?

Comment: @mcgraphix updated a bit. Please let me know if you need additional information

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the expected behavior of the service if getEmployee is called before getCompany is called? You should at least check for company being null before attempting to use it. Also, you may want to consider storing the company in a property that you can access in your service. NOTE: I'm prefixing the property name with an underscore just to make a distinction between the public api and this pseudo-private property:

```
{
    _company: null,
    getCompany: function() {
        var self = this;
        var url = '...';
        return $http.get(url).then(function(comp){
            self._company = comp;
            return self._company;
        });
    },
    getEmployee: function() {
        var self = this;
        if (!self._company) {
            return null; //or throw error or return rejected promise: $q.reject('company is null')
        } else {
            var url = '...';
            var name = self._company.name;
            return http.get(url);
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, you can (and should) test your service separately from your controller now. In your controller test, you can just spyOn your service methods without it calling through to the server. And when you test your service, you can just set the service._company to a mock value when testing the getEmployee method.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is in your Service. "company" should be the object literal since you access .name over it else it will through an error which you have specified.

Try below code:

### Service

```
var company = {};

function getCompany() {
    $http.get(url).then(function(comp){
          company = comp;
          return company;
    })
}

function getEmployee = function() {
    var name = company.name
    $http.get(url).then(function(employee){
        // do stuff    
    }
}
```

It should work.

Comment: thanks but the line company = comp should declare it since comp is a object already. I do declared company as var company in the beginning. Thanks :D

Comment: In jasmine unit testing, every test case (it()) has its own scope. So if you call getCompany() in first test then it does not mean that in second test case, company var will maintain its previous value, while it would be null again. So define company as var company = {}; it would work at both of the cases(dev & test).